# Adding iframe to google code project hosting wiki page

Tags: iframe, wiki, embed, google-code

Is it possible to add iframe inside google code project hosting wiki?

I wan't to embed an external application using iframe in my google project page. My idea is to create a google wiki page and add the iframe in that page.

How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Project hosting on Google Code doesn't support iframes directly, but there is support for embedding gadgets within a wiki page. There are docs describing how to use gadgets on the support project wiki:

http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/WorkingWithGoogleGadgets

Comment: Why didn't the author accept this answer? It is useful for me. Thanks Nathan.

Answer (score 0):

You could try embedding an HTML gadget ([dooWiki](http://doowikis.com)) into your Google page which would then give you the ability to bring in other content like an iframe would.  What's also nice is that the dooWiki sizes with your page (like a div) instead of you having to set "height" and "width" parameters of an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to embed a video you can use this syntax:

```xml
 <wiki:video url="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d2QWXgVdlJU"/>
```

So iframe is not required

Comment: I've formatted the code; see here for how to post code in Markdown: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code